# Change radius for proportional editing in Blender 3.5

Tags: proportional-editing

since none of the previous answers worked and the editing mode might have changed since the last questions and answers, I would like to ask the following again:

How do I change the radius for proportional editing?

- I added a UV sphere.
- If I go into *editing mode* and extrude parts of the surface (Hotkey E), only the surface part is extruded independent of wether the editing mode is on or off.
- If I go to *Modifier Properties*, than to *Add Modifier, Subdivision Surface*, parts of the neighbouring surfaces are also extruded slightly, inpedentent of wether the proportional editing mode is turned on or off.
- I can't change the radius of the neighbours being affected by page-up/page-down or with the mouse wheel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every action in blender pops up a little black setting menu on the bottom left corner which you can tweak settings , as for the extrude it isn't usual to use proportional editing but it is inside that window and you can use it .

[image]

as you can se up here i uploaded an animated image that shows how it's done but again it is not a usual way to model anything in blender and i don't think that once you get pro in blender you're going to use it ever .

and finally if you get your answer don't forget to like and accept this answer .

Comment: The result looks the same as just mowing the selected face with proportional editing On.

Comment: kind of , but no this is an extrude command and it will make a new face

Comment: Good spot! ..  it's there, alright, but affects only the implicit 'G' after face-generation.. so _always_ leaves you with pathological topo.. coincident vertices after the operation. I dunno, I think I'd warn against ever using it.

Comment: @RobinBetts Robin my friend i never ever used it i guess blender dev team just put it there to exists, its kind of logical  , also coincident vertices are not a big deal it is logical too , because this is the way that blender  proportional editing works , not for these simple models , but maybe you want to create some sort of abstract model that needs it and maybe it could help idk